# Custom date verification - BASH - using just grep or awk etc

Tags: bash, validation, date, awk, grep

I saw couple of posts (some depends upon `date -d $xyz` to verify) but I'm trying to create an `until` loop where the user should be re-prompted to enter the value of a date format until it matches the custom date format.

My date format (what I need for Splunk) is `m/d/yyyy:h:m:s` or `mm/dd/yyyy:hh:mm:ss`

which means, if `m` (month number) is a single digit lets say `1 for January`, then both `1` or `01` values are possible for date format but `0` or `00` is NOT a valid value. Value range is `01-to->12` or `1-to->12` but not greater than 12.

Similarly, the same rule applies to `d` (day number), it can be `01-to->10-to->31` or `1-to->31` but not `00` or more than `31` and all other `yyyy` (year), `h` (hour), `m` (minute), `s` (second) part.

What could be a minimal code (obfuscated is fine) to do this verification in BASH? It seems like `date -d ???` doesn't provides this custom kind of verification for date/times!

OK, I can write one verifyDateFormatfunc() to do this, but I know there are people who have already written a one-liner / minimal snippet to verify this for sure. `grep -f ..` (where bunch of regex are listed line by line for all possible combinations, again the main code will look very minimal if I follow this? as the patterns sitting in `-f file` for `grep` will be transparent to a user) -or creating a map funcation (based on delimiters) for value ranges?

**Possible** values:

```
1/03/2017:23:0:15
02/4/2017:0:1:2
09/05/2017:10:10:0
10/6/2017:12:14:16
```

Comment: So, would you say `2/31/2017:0:0:0` is a valid date?

Comment: You can use your arithmetic operators to validate date/time components with leading zeros, e.g. `echo $((01))` is `1`.

Comment: @randomir :) nice catch. As splunk accepts both 01 or 1 as valid, Im now thinking just go with no leading zero format. Still Feb is a special case.

Comment: Doing this will give remove leading 0's from a given number: `a="9/09/2019:00:00:00"; echo "$a" | grep -o "[0-9]\{1,2\}/[0-9]\{1,2\}/[1-9][0-9]\{3\}:[0-9]\{1,2\}:[0-9]\{1,2\}:[0-9]\{1,2\}" | sed "s/\([\/:]\)0/\1/g" ; echo $?
9/9/2019:0:0:0 0(success)` and will give me the date time format which Splunk can read, next I can put some checks around individual values (delimited by `/` or `:`)... or wrap it in a minimal code for a verifyDateTime function. I'll share what I can get but would be great if there's any other minimal one-liner/code to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an unholy *extended regular expression* (POSIX ERE):

```
^([1-9]|1[0-2]|0[1-9])/([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/[0-9]{4}:([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])$
```

that will test for the date/time patterns you specified (`m/d/yyyy:h:m:s` and `mm/dd/yyyy:hh:mm:ss`), with:

- month: `1-12`, `01-12`
- day: `1-31`, `01-31`
- year: `0000-9999`
- hour: `0-23`, `00-23`
- minute: `0-59`, `00-59`
- second: `0-59`, `00-59`

You can use in an **`awk` program** that will exit with success (exit code 0) if the (first) line is a valid date/time (wrapped in a shell function that tests the first argument, for convenience):

```
#!/bin/bash
is_datetime_valid() {
    awk '{exit $0!~"^([1-9]|1[0-2]|0[1-9])/([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/[0-9]{4}:([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])$"}' <<<"$1"
}
```

Or, if you prefer a **pure `bash` solution** (with ERE support in `bash` v3.0+):

```
#!/bin/bash
is_datetime_valid() {
    local pat='^([1-9]|1[0-2]|0[1-9])/([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/[0-9]{4}:([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])$'
    [[ $1 =~ $pat ]]
}
```

You can use it like:

```
if is_datetime_valid "1/03/2017:23:0:15"; then
    # yup, it's valid
else
    # ney, it's invalid
fi
```

Tested on a few examples:

```
#!/bin/bash
samples=(
    "1/03/2017:23:0:15" "02/4/2017:0:1:2" "09/05/2017:10:10:0" "10/6/2017:12:14:16"
    "00/03/2017:23:0:15" "1/33/2017:23:0:15"
)
for dt in "${samples[@]}"; do
    if is_datetime_valid "$dt"; then
        echo "$dt is valid"
    else
        echo "$dt is invalid"
    fi
done
```

Gives:

```
1/03/2017:23:0:15 is valid
02/4/2017:0:1:2 is valid
09/05/2017:10:10:0 is valid
10/6/2017:12:14:16 is valid
00/03/2017:23:0:15 is invalid
1/33/2017:23:0:15 is invalid
```

Comment: Awesome, except it'll catch 0000 for yyyy so first number for year can't be `0`.

Comment: What's the valid range for year, in your case?

Comment: I would say, more precisely anytime after Splunk was born (2003 onwards), but i'll do it. Thanks.

Comment: You can then use `[2-9][0-9]{3}` for the year field (if `2000-9999` is ok).

Comment: This is great! I think the only thing I have to nail down now is checking for February for day# 28/29 thingy based on a given leap year. I'll try that later but initial verification looks perfect. This is indeed very simple one-liner solution. Thanks. `is_splunkdatetime_valid 2/30/2017:23:0:15; echo $?
0
`. Lol: http://www.refinery29.com/2017/02/142002/why-does-february-have-28-days

Comment: You're welcome. The leap year and Feb29 is only one of the issues. There are leap seconds, DST changes, "missing days/years", [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/404556). Truly validating dates is really, really, really hard.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether using BSD date is an option for you, but it has what you are looking for.

There the date checker function can look like this

```
is_datetime_valid() {
   date -j -f "%m/%d/%Y:%T"  $1 1> /dev/null 2>&1
   return $?
}
```

Comment: nice! That's good to know and very clean one liner. Most probably the slave server used by Jenkins is based on an Ubuntu image so I'll prefer the grep awk way but this one is definitely one of the answer for a BSD based system

Comment: @ArunSangal : try `date --date="13/3/2017 23:00:15" "+%m/%d/%Y:%T"`, this will produce `date: invalid date \`13/3/2017 23:00:15'`, running on a debian type linux (and any others with a modern `date` (If you're lucky ;-) ). Good luck to all.